# Checking memory footprint in Arduino

Tags: memory-management, arduino

I'm working on a simple project with my Arduino. Recently I had to convert one of my variables to a long instead of an int, and in order to keep things simple I just moved over all the numbers that it interacts with (so I don't have to worry about cross-type comparisons and math). This seems wasteful, but it's just a clock for myself, and I don't care that much.

It has, however, made me wonder about how much memory I am using. I doubt it's an issue, but I realized I don't know any way to check.

So, is there a way to check the amount of memory being used by an Arduino?

Ideally, I'd like to print out the current memory / total available over the serial connection.

Comment: Give http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ a try, though this is programming related, I think you'll get a better response from the community who does more work specifically with microcontrollers such as the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks, if I don't get what I need I'll try that.

Comment: Alright, lets see what they say http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/24269/7247

Answer (score 3):

You could use this. It will give you an idea about where you are:

```
Serial.print(availableMemory());

// free RAM check for debugging. SRAM for ATmega328p = 2048Kb.
int availableMemory() {
    // Use 1024 with ATmega168
    int size = 2048;
    byte *buf;
    while ((buf = (byte *) malloc(--size)) == NULL);
        free(buf);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: This only measures heap usage (ignores the stack and globals) and will fail if the heap happens to be fragmented.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [MemoryFree](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory). This library has worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is detailed information about this over at the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory), that's where I found the method I've been using:

MemoryFree.h:

```cpp
// MemoryFree library based on code posted here:
// http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1213583720/15
//
// Extended by Matthew Murdoch to include walking of the free list.

#ifndef MEMORY_FREE_H
#define MEMORY_FREE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  int freeMemory();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

---

MemoryFree.cpp:

```cpp
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include &lt;Arduino.h&gt;
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif

extern unsigned int __heap_start;
extern void *__brkval;

/*
 * The free list structure as maintained by the 
 * avr-libc memory allocation routines.
 */
struct __freelist {
  size_t sz;
  struct __freelist *nx;
};

/* The head of the free list structure */
extern struct __freelist *__flp;

#include "MemoryFree.h";

/* Calculates the size of the free list */
int freeListSize() {
  struct __freelist* current;
  int total = 0;

  for (current = __flp; current; current = current->nx) {
    total += 2; /* Add two bytes for the memory block's header  */
    total += (int) current->sz;
  }

  return total;
}

int freeMemory() {
  int free_memory;

  if ((int)__brkval == 0) {
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)&__heap_start);
  } else {
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)__brkval);
    free_memory += freeListSize();
  }
  return free_memory;
}
```

---

Example sketch:

```cpp
#include &lt;MemoryFree.h&gt;

// On Arduino Duemilanove with ATmega328:
//
// Reported free memory with str commented out:
// 1824 bytes
//
// Reported free memory with str and Serial.println(str) uncommented:
// 1810
//
// Difference: 14 bytes (13 ascii chars + null terminator)

// 14-bytes string
//char str[] = "Hello, world!";


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}


void loop() {
    //Serial.println(str);

    Serial.print("freeMemory()=");
    Serial.println(freeMemory());

    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on Esben's answer i wrote this optimized version:

```
int biggestMemoryBlock(uint16_t min,uint16_t max)
{
  if (min==max-1)
    return min;

  int size=max;
  int lastSize=size;
  byte *buf;
  while ((buf = (byte *) malloc(size)) == NULL)
  {
    lastSize=size;
    size-=(max-min)/2;
  };

  free(buf);
  return biggestMemoryBlock(size,lastSize);
};


int biggestMemoryBlock() 
{
    return biggestMemoryBlock(0,4096);
}
```

On Arduino Uno it takes just 1 millisecond or less, instead of 13-20 ms with the original function. The constant must be at least the total memory (in bytes) on the board.